# Apache SSHD client: authenticate with identity file

Tags: java, apache-sshd

I am trying to write an SSH client using MINA SSHD, connecting with an identity file generated by openSSH (`id_rsa` and the corresponding public key `id_rsa.pub`)

The [docs](https://github.com/apache/mina-sshd/blob/master/docs/client-setup.md) say to write something along these lines:

```
    SshClient client = SshClient.setUpDefaultClient();
    client.start();

    // using the client for multiple sessions...
    try (ClientSession session = client.connect(user, host, port)
                .verify(1000)
                .getSession()) {
        session.addPublicKeyIdentity(/* ...key-pair... */);
        session.auth().verify(1000);
        // ...
    }
    client.stop();
```

How do I build the argument to the method `addPublicKeyIdentity`? How do I convert my identity file to a `KeyPair`?

Many thanks

Comment: If your `id_rsa` file is in `~/.ssh`, it works out of the box. No need to call `session.addPublicKeyIdentity`. I haven't found a way yet to load a _different_ private key file though.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use `org.apache.sshd.common.keyprovider.FileKeyPairProvider` instead.

Example:

```
FileKeyPairProvider provider = new FileKeyPairProvider(/*Path to your privateKey*/);
provider.setPasswordFinder(FilePasswordProvider.of(/*your private key passphrase*/));
session.setKeyIdentityProvider(provider);
```